# python NameError: name 'memberno' is not defined

Tags: python

my code is giving me the error of

```
Destination[index]=inode*dof-dof
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I have searched for this error but i cant figure out the problem in this code.Please help me...

```
import numpy as np

class memberdata(object):
    def__init__(self,memberno=None,backnode=None,forenode=None,materialno=None):
        self.memberno=memberno
        self.backnode=backnode
        self.forenode=forenode
        self.materialno=materialno
member=[]
member.append(memberdata('10','2','3','1'))

print "enter dof"
dof=raw_input()
dof=int(dof)
def get_destination(memberno):
    inode = member[memberno-1].backnode
    inode=int(inode)
    jnode = member[memberno-1].forenode
    jnode=int(jnode)
    Destination=[]  
    index=0
    Destination[index]=inode*dof-dof
    for i in range(dof):
        index=index+1
        Destination[index]=Destination[index-1]+1
    index=index+1
    Destination[index]=jnode*dof-dof
    for i in range(dof):
        index=index+1
        Destination[index]=Destination[index-1]+1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_destination(memberno)
```

Comment: Why does your title contain an otherwise unmentioned error?

Answer (score 1):

```
Destination=[]  
index=0
Destination[index]=inode*dof-dof
```

Here, you create an empty list with `[]` and then try to assign index 0, where `Destination[0]` doesn't yet exist. The list holds 0 values, hence any index you try to assign will be out of range.

If you simply want to add some value to the list, use

```
Destination.append(inode*dof-dof)
```

Comment: That's the error theyll get after fixing `get_destination(memberno)`... :p (not sure if the OP means to use `dof` there, as that's their only input.)

Comment: @JonClements You're right. I didn't look that far.. usually spend more effort reading the question than reading the title